# How to do assembly arithmetic with different types of variables?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to do simple arithmetic for one of my class homework. I have 4 variables A = 38d, B = 0010 1001b, C = A5h and D = 85d. and I need to perform (a-b)+(c-d). I think I have figured out the arithmetic part but I am confused about variable conversion. I used DWORD to store the 4 variables but not sure If I need to convert them before to hex. Here is where I am currently and it is giving me error:"undefined symbol a5h"

```
 .data
   var1 DWORD  38d
   var2 DWORD  00101001b
 var3 DWORD  A5h
 var4 DWORD  85d
 
 ;result2 DWORD  ?  Not intialized 
 .code
 mov eax, var1   ;move variable 1 in register
 sub eax, var2   ; sub variable 2 from var 1
 mov ebx, var3   ;  move var 3 to register
 sub ebx, var4   ;
 add eax,ebx     ;
 Call WriteInt   
 
 call DumpRegs             ;dump the registers
```

Comment: `A5h` is also a valid label name, so that's what it'll be interpreted as. For hexadecimal literals that start with A..F you need to put a 0 at the start, i.e. `0A5h`.

Comment: Also, unless you have somehow overridden the default radix, the `d` suffix is redudant and just adds visual clutter. Just write `38` and `85`.

Comment: thanks.that worked I knew it already that I need to put 0 infront of hex literals but I wasn't sure as I was thinking may be I need to convert them first them all to hex or decimal and then perform arithmetic

Comment: `38` and `26h` are just different visual representations of the same value.

Comment: When the variable values `38d`,`101001b`,`0A5h`, `85d` are known at asm-time, it is easy because assembler makes the radix conversion for you, so you can write them into data definition `as is`.   
It will be more difficult if those values are to be read from keyboard at run-time, you would have to parse the digits and letters, recognize radix in the last character and branch to the appropriate conversion subroutine.