# Code is not displaying the result in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

```
A DWORD 38h
B DWORD 0010 1001b
C DWORD A5h
D DWORD 85d

;Calculate A = (A - B) + (C - D). Where A = 38d, B = 0010 1001b, C = A5h and D = 85d.  

mov EAX, 0
mov EAX, A
sub EAX, B

mov EBX, C
sub EBX, D

add EAX, EBX
mov A, EAX
call WriteInt
```

Comment: See also the similar question of your schoolmate Ravin at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177376/how-to-do-assembly-arithmetic-with-different-types-of-variables#comment117000729_66177376

Answer (score -1):

```
.data
valA DWORD 38d
valB DWORD 101001b
valC DWORD 0A5h
valD DWORD 85d

.code
mov EAX, 0            ; setting the register to 0
mov EAX, valA         ; moving the value in a to eax register
sub EAX, valB         ; value A - Value B

mov EBX, valC         ; moving the value in c to ebx
sub EBX, valD         ; value C - Value D

add EAX, EBX          ; (A - B) + (C - D)
mov valA, EAX         ; set answer to Aand move it to EAX
Call WriteInt

call DumpRegs   ;shows content
```